# Relation between interior and boundary points on two topologies

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I have a proof of the following statements , which  I am not sure is correct 
Prove : Let T(1) and T(2) be topologies on X with  , with T(1) contained in T(2), and let A be a subset of X Then:
a.The T(1) interior of A is a subset of the T(2) interior of A.
b. The T(2) boundary of A is a subset of the T(1) boundary of A.
Proof: (a):Let {G(i)} element of T(1) be the class of all open subsets of A , and let {E(i)} element of T(2) be the class of all open subsets of A . By definition int(A)= U G(i) , and also int(A)=U E(i) . Since T(1) is a subset of T(2) we have U G(i) is a subset of U E(i) .So the T(1) interior of A is a subset of the T(2) interior of A.
Proof:(b): In my book it is proved that cl(A) = int(A) U b(A) , where cl and b denote the closure and boundary operators respectively. From this I deduce that b(A)=cl(A)/int(A). Now by part (a) U G(i) is a subset of U E(i) , so we get that cl(A)/U E(i) is a subset of cl(A)/ U G(i) hence the T(2) boundary of A is a subset of the T(2) boundary of A.
          Is this all correct?

Comment: The first part is good.  The second confusing with a vacuous conclusion.

Comment: So how does one go about in proving the second part??

Answer (score 0):

As it is extremely hard to follow your notation I cannot comment upon your proof of b.  Notice your conclusion.  It is not what you intended to prove.

Besides showing T1 interior subset T2 interior,
you need to show T2 closure subset T1 closure.