# Boundary points and interior points in different topologies

Tags: general-topology

I have asked this before and have done some work on it , but no one could understand me , because my notation was terrible

> Let $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ be topologies on $X$ with $\mathcal{T}_1$ coarser than $\mathcal{T}_2$, i.e. $\mathcal{T}_1 \subset \mathcal{T}_2$, and let $A \subset X$. Then prove:
>
> - The $\mathcal{T}_1$-interior of $A$ is a subset of the $\mathcal{T}_2$-interior of $A$.
> - The $\mathcal{T}_2$-boundary of $A$ is a subset of the $\mathcal{T}_1$-boundary of $A$.

Comment: I've typed up the question from your image. It would be helpful for us to know your thoughts on the question so far - do you have any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary case: Assume that $x$ is a $\tau_{2}$-boundary of $A$, then given $\tau_{1}$-open set $G$ of $x$, since $G\in\tau_{2}$, the definition of boundary implies that $G\cap A\ne\emptyset$ and $G\cap A^{c}\ne\emptyset$. Since this is true for all $\tau_{1}$-open $G$ of $x$, again the definition of boundary implies that $x$ is a $\tau_{1}$-boundary of $A$.

Comment: Thanks , and the interior case ??

Comment: That is easier, you may try some work then I will help you.

Comment: Thanks , you may what to try reading what i am saying here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525209/relation-between-interior-and-boundary-points-on-two-topologies

Comment: Okay, actually it works, but here's my approach: Assume that $x$ is a $\tau_{1}$-interior of $A$, then there is some $\tau_{1}$-open $G$ such that $x\in G\subseteq A$, but $G\in\tau_{2}$, so we have found an $\tau_{2}$-open $G$ of $x$ such that $G\subseteq A$, in particular, $x$ belongs to $\tau_{2}$-interior of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your interest .... OK so something I am doing is right ...